# How to make DotNetNuke Captcha control to show an error if it left blank

Tags: dotnetnuke, captcha

I took a captcha control on my page :

```
 <dnn:CaptchaControl ID="CaptchaControl1" runat="server" CaptchaHeight="50px"    CaptchaWidth="150px" ErrorMessage="incorrect"     />
```

if captcha is incorrect the error message will be shown but if it left blank it shows no error.is there any way to make it show an error when it is blank?

thanks

Comment: I don't have time for a great answer here, so I'm just going to leave this as a comment. You're going to want to do this client-side, I think. Set ClientIDMode="static" on the captcha control. Then, give it a cssclass="CaptchaRequired". Then, use a jquery to establish a required field $(".CaptchaRequired").next().next() (This will select the textbox). Here's a great validation library: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 0):

Hmm Iam not sure but I would try:

```
asp:RequiredFieldValidator
```

there you can enter the properties:

```
ControlToValidate="yourCaptchaControlID"
Display="Dynamic"
Enabled="True"
```

maybe you have to set the following property at your captcha control:

```
CausesValidation="True"
```

This is working client side, too.

hope this helps.
best regards, noone.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1) Add a css class name to the captcha control (i.e. CssClass="captcha")

```
<dnn:captchacontrol id="ctlCaptcha" cssclass="Normal captcha" runat="server" />
```

2) Create a javascript function:

```
function validateCaptcha() {
    var captValue = $('.captcha input').val();
    if (captValue == '') {
        alert('You must enter a value for the CAPTCHA control.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

3) Call the function on your submit button:

```
<asp:linkbutton id="btnUpdate" runat="server" OnClientClick="return validateCaptcha()">Update</asp:linkbutton>
```

Comment: UPDATE: You may need to test if the CAPTCHA value is valid on the server side (i.e. ctlCaptcha.IsValid) otherwise you can type any character(s) you want and it will accept it.